# VBA Excel: как определить, что курсор покинул поле кнопки

Tags: excel, button, vba, mouse-event, координаты

Подскажите как надежно определить, что курсор мышки покинул поле кнопки в Excel.

Основная задача следующая: когда курсор мышки попадает на поле кнопки, текст кнопки меняется, когда покидает поле кнопки - текст меняется обратно.

В нормальных языках есть события `onMouseOver` и `onMouseOut`, но в excel VBA последнего события нет.

Я сделал следующим образом: если курсор находится около края кнопки, то я меняю текст

```
' наведение на кнопку
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim Delta As Integer
    Delta = 5

    If X > Delta And X < CommandButton1.Width - Delta And Y > Delta And Y < CommandButton1.Height - Delta Then
        CommandButton1.Caption = "XXX"
    Else
        CommandButton1.Caption = "YYY"
    End If
End Sub
```

Но если быстро возить курсором, то код может не сработать (мышка успеет проскочить мою границу).

**Как все таки реализовать правильно?**

Или проще - как мне получить событие onMouseOver со всей страницу excel, я бы тогда зная координаты кнопки смог бы обработать все сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отслеживние координат указателя мыши с отображением этих координат и имени ячейки или объекта.

Автор:  *Владимир Захаров (Microsoft MVP)*

```
Option Explicit

' ZVI:2008-07_05 http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum.php?thread_id=4656'
Type POINTAPI
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Dim DoStop As Boolean

' Запуск цикла'
Sub RunRangeFromPoint()
  Dim obj As Object, NewValue As String
  Dim cpos As POINTAPI
  With ActiveWindow
    Do
      GetCursorPos cpos
      Set obj = .RangeFromPoint(cpos.x, cpos.y)
      Cells(5, 2) = cpos.x
      Cells(6, 2) = cpos.y
      With Лист1.[A1]
        If .Value <> TypeName(obj) Then .Value = TypeName(obj)
      End With
      With Лист1.[A2]
        Select Case TypeName(obj)
          Case "Range":   NewValue = obj.Address(0, 0)
          Case "Nothing": NewValue = "Nothing"
          Case Else:      NewValue = obj.Name
        End Select
        If .Value <> NewValue Then .Value = NewValue
      End With
      DoEvents
    Loop Until DoStop
  End With
  With Лист1
    .[A2].Value = ""
    .[A1].Value = "Stop"
  End With
  Set obj = Nothing
End Sub

' Кнопка Вкл/Откл'
Sub StartStop()
  DoStop = Not DoStop
  DoEvents
  If DoStop = False Then RunRangeFromPoint
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. по сути 1) я использую функцию WinAPI для определения позиции курсора мышки 2) постоянно определяю где находится курсор и потом через `DoEvents` даю отработать другим компонентам excel, таким образом избегая зависания программы? Но это кажется как-то сильно усложнено - неужто у excel нет встроенных средств для решения подобной задачи?

Comment: Да, макрос постоянно работает. Без *WinAPI* и прерываний решения не знаю.